# How to display and hide columns based on the two dropdown selection using ag grid

Tags: drop-down-menu, angular7, ag-grid, show-hide

Basically, I have two dropdowns a and b.
Based on the combination of these two dropdowns Ineed to hide / show colums using ag grid.

Eg: if I choose 'xyz' in dropdown a and '123' in dropdown b, 2 columns wiil be displayed. Similarly if choose dropdown 'ghj' and '456' in dropdown b, some ther 3 columns will be selected and the first 2 columns will be no longer be visible / available.

I can use if else conditionsbut I need to check for all the possible combinations. Is there an easy way to do so?

```
dropdown a
     onReportingType(e) {
        // console.log(e);
        this.reportData = e;
        this.reportSelArr.push(this.reportData);
        console.log(this.reportSelArr);
    }
dropdown b
    onDataPoint(e) {
        console.log(e);
        this.dataPointData = e;
        this.dataPointSelArr.push(this.dataPointData);
        console.log(this.dataPointSelArr);
        this.addRatingCol();
    }
```

Condition applied for now

```
    addRatingCol() {
    // console.log(this.reportSelArr);
    // console.log(this.dataPointSelArr);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.reportSelArr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.dataPointSelArr.length; j++) {
            if (this.reportSelArr[i].reportingTypeName === 'Outstanding') {
                if (this.dataPointSelArr[j].dataPointName === 'Rating') {
                    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['newRatingName', 'newRatingReleaseDate'], true);
                    return true;
                } else if (this.dataPointSelArr[j].dataPointName === 'Rating Outlook') {
                    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['newOutlookName', 'newOutlookDate', 'outlookEndDate'], true);
                } else if (this.dataPointSelArr[j].dataPointName === 'Rating Watch') {
                    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['newRatingWatchName', 'newRatingWatchDate', 'ratingwatchEndDate'], true);
                }
            }
        } // end of the for loop
    }
if (this.addCol === true && this.addReport === true){
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['newRatingName', 'newRatingReleaseDate'], true);
    } else {
    this.gridColumnApi.setColumnsVisible(['newRatingName', 'newRatingReleaseDate'], false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6..

Instead of the 2 for loops i would prefer using filter for the first loop and finding whether it has the reporting type as outstanding.

```
const outstanding = this.reportSelArr.filter(elem => elem.reportingTypeName === 'Outstanding')
```

i would then use the return value of the filter to determine whether or not to run the second for loop which can be through a map.

```
if (outstanding) {
this.dataPointSelArr.map(elem => {
const { dataPointName } = elem
 switch(dataPointName) {
   case 'Rating': {
      //statements;
      break;
   }
   case 'Rating Outlook': {
      //statements;
      break;
   }
   case 'Rating Watch':{
//statements;
      break;
}
   default: {
      //statements;
      break;
   }
}
    
  })
}
```